# How to check all the sub-folders and files in the app storage in a flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, appstorage

I can't check the subfolders and files inside Flutter's app storage. I can't just go to the emulator or real device's files and access all the cache and app storage files. My storage is filled automatically with any library, I need to delete that, and for that I need to check the exact locations of files.